# Java HashMap adds value to the head of the list

Tags: java, hashmap

I was working on java HashMaps and found that it adds values to the head of the list. For example ,

hm.put(mike,2);
hm.put(andrew,3);

Now,if i print the hasmap using iterator,i get

andrew 3

mike 2

I want the items to be added in the FIFO fashion rather than LIFO fashion ... Is there a way to do it?

Comment: A `Map` (and hash structures in general) is not a `List`, check the interface spec.  If you want ordering, you need something specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Map abstraction in Java does not play well with notions of LIFO or FIFO.  These concepts primarily apply to ordered sequences, while Maps are stored in an ordering that is entirely independent of the orde in which the values are inserted in order to maximize efficiency.  For example, the HashMap uses hashing to store its values, and the more randomly the hash function distributes its values the better the performance.  Similarly, the TreeMap uses a balanced binary search tree, which stores its values in sorted order to guarantee fast lookups.

However, Java does have a really cool class called the LinkedHashMap that I believe is exactly what you're looking for.  It gives the speed of a HashMap while guaranteeing a predictable traversal order which is defined by the order in which you insert the elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try using linkedHashMap

Answer (score 7):

Try using a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead. I don't think HashMaps guarantee order.

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    lHashMap.put("1", "One");
    lHashMap.put("2", "Two");
    lHashMap.put("3", "Three");

    Collection c = lHashMap.values();
    Iterator itr = c.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```

output

```
One
Two
Three
```

Comment: `HashMap` and `Hashtable` do not guarantee ordering.

Comment: Agree. LinkedHashMap == HashMap + LinkedList

Comment: @卢声远 LinkedHashMap is not a List

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use a Queue?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

HashMaps are not ordered, the fact that you are getting them returned from the iterator in the 'wrong' order is just a function of how the hashing is happening on the key.

How specifically do you want to use this datastructure?